# x was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Alright so I am fairly new to all of this but I made an attempt to code a little project selector batch file thinger. (Not really sure what to call it but it's the equivalent of pressing the Win + P and selecting it from there. Anyhow, I made this little thing up and once I run it, it all goes smoothly and it does work, but for whatever reason when I confirm my choice it says `Y was unexpected at this time. N was unexpected at this time.` Not a big deal, just wondering why it happens and how I can fix it. Thank you in advance :)

```
@ECHO OFF
color 0b
title Display Selector by Nicholas Deckman
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
CLS
echo       -----------------------------------
echo            Display Selector              
echo                     by Nicholas Deckman  
echo       -----------------------------------
echo.
echo.
:Begin
ECHO 1.PC Display Only
ECHO 2.External Display Only
ECHO 3.Extend Display
ECHO 4.Duplicate
ECHO.

CHOICE /C 1234 /M "Enter the number of your choice:"

:: Note - list ERRORLEVELS in decreasing order
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO Duplicate
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO Extend
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO External
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Internal

:Internal
echo.
ECHO Internal Display Selected
displayswitch.exe /internal
GOTO Confirm

:External
echo.
ECHO External Display Selected
displayswitch.exe /external
GOTO Confirm

:Extend
echo.
ECHO Extend Display Selected
displayswitch.exe /extend
GOTO Confirm

:Duplicate
echo.
ECHO Duplicate Display Selected
displayswitch.exe /clone
GOTO Confirm

:Confirm
echo.
CHOICE /T 15 /D N /M "Is this the setting you would like to keep? If no option is selected in 15 seconds, the display will revert to [PC ONLY] Display: "

IF ERRORLEVEL Y GOTO YES
IF ERRORLEVEL N GOTO NO


:NO
echo.
ECHO Reverting to [PC ONLY] Display
ECHO Reverted Success!
echo.
GOTO InternalBegin

:InternalBegin
echo.
ECHO Internal Display Selected
displayswitch.exe /internal
GOTO Begin

:YES
echo.
color 4
ECHO CMD FAIL
ECHO Thank you for using the Display Selector Tool by Nicholas Deckman
pause
GOTO End

:End
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `IF ERRORLEVEL Y`.

Comment: Run in a command prompt window `choice /?` and it can be read: *The ERRORLEVEL environment variable is set to the __index__ of the key that was selected __from the set of choices__. The first choice listed returns a value of 1, the second a value of 2, and so on.* So on `/C POXD` instead of `/C 1234` pressing `D` sets errorlevel to `4`, `X` sets `3`, `O` sets `2` and `P` sets `1`. BTW: The line `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Internal` is unnecessary in your code. Read also the MS support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have confused how `IF ERRORLEVEL` works. This statement only accepts a **integer**.

---

For example this works:

```
CHOICE /T 15 /D N /M "Is this the setting you would like to keep? If no option is selected in 15 seconds, the display will revert to [PC ONLY] Display: "

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO NO
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO YES
```

Because, by default, `CHOICE` gives an YN option. And, here's the errorlevel for default choice.

- 2 `==` N
- 1 `==` Y